# Custom view doesn't update inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, view

I have a project in which I have to build views inside a custom Layout. This layout represents the concept of **View** in MVP architecture and it lives in a Fragment. The view should be updated by the Presenter whenever an event happens, by calling the **View** and finally that will update `TextViews` inside the **View**. But it seems that after the View is initialized, nothing gets updated anymore.

If my presenter calls the **View** that contains my `TextView` - nothing. If I try to update the `TextView` directly, from the fragment then it works. I can't really understand what is happening and why it doesn't get updated from within the layout that contains that `TextView`.

MyCustomView:

```
class MyCustomView(fragment: MyFragment): MyViewInterface, FrameLayout(fragment.context) {

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_fancy_layout, this)
    }

    override fun getView(): View {
        return this
    }

    override fun setData(uiModel: UiModel) {
        textview_name.text = uiModel.name
    }
}
```

MyFragment:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var view: MyViewInterface
    @Inject lateinit var presenter: MyCustomPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ... dagger injection ...
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return this.view.getView()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        presenter.setData(...some ID to fetch data from API...)
        //textview_name.text = "blue" //this works instead
    }
}
```

MyPresenter:

```
class MyPresenter @Inject constructor(
        private val repo: MyRepository,
        private val view: MyViewInterface
) {

    fun setData(productCode: String) {
        .. some code ...
        view.setData(it) //call to my view          
    }
}
```

MyViewInterface:

```
interface MyViewInterface {
    fun getView(): View

    fun setData(uiModel: UiModel)
}
```

Comment: All I can think of is the view's instance is not the same in your UI and presenter.

Comment: You were right. It seems that Dagger was injecting 2 different views instead of a scoped one. You can make it an answer if you want and I'll mark it.

Comment: Sure, why not. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can think of is the view's instance is not the same in your UI and presenter. I dont know your Dagger's code so I do not have any suggestions to fix it.

You could move the view away from MyPresenter's constructor and set it in MyFragment.onCreate after injection.

Comment: I've used wrong @MyScope annotation so it wasn't injecting it as "per fragment" but re-instantiating it every time, rookie's mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Because of you just inflate when create view

```
    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_fancy_layout, this)
    }
```

add invalidate view in update data function

```
  override fun setData(uiModel: UiModel) {
        textview_name.text = uiModel.name
         this.invalidate()
         this.requestLayout()

    }
```

Comment: I don't really think it makes sense to re-inflate the `layout`. Although I did tried it just to understand if it works (it doesn't by the way) it wouldn't be clean or efficient approach.

Comment: overlay after update data need a refreshing layout, for a refreshing view, you have many approaches like invalidate layout or...

Comment: I've tried many but none worked. In the end @vilpe89 was right. I would still avoid re-inflating layouts if I can.